# Не(_)понятно и при(_)чем

Tags: орфография

Интересный спор вызвала фраза собеседника: Только *непонятно, причем* тут Содом и Гоморра?

Объясните подробнее, как в данном контексте пишутся слова *"непонятно"* и *"причем".*

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Хороший вопрос, на самом деле. В обоих случаях можно поспорить.

"При чем" - это местоимение (местоименное наречие) и, к сожалению, для этого нет единой рекомендации. Кузнецов, например, противоречит Лопатину.
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC&all=x 
Думаю, что прав Лопатин и другие авторы, писать надо раздельно.

А вот с "непонятно" ситуация следующая. "Не понятно" можно, конечно, трактовать как предикативное наречие, но даже это не гарантирует слитного написания, вполне возможно и раздельное написание, если подчеркиваетсся отрицание. Причем на случай вопросительного предложения есть специальная оговорка.

*Примечание 1...

При логическом подчеркивании отрицания в вопросительных предложениях "не" пишется раздельно с предикативными наречиями, например: Не удивительно ли, что посредственное произведение так разрекламировано?*

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#%D0%B7_09

Плюс "(не)понятно" - это совершенно не очевидное наречие, можно трактовать и как причастие, но этот вариант я сейчас не буду развивать, и так понятно, что написание может быть двояким.

Какой вариант выбрать, я бы не рискнул советовать, не зная контекста.

В нейтральном стиле, наверное слитно: *"Только непонятно, при чем тут Содом и Гоморра?",* для акцентации "не понятно" - раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

*Только **неп**онятно, пр**и ч**ём тут Содом и Гоморра*.

*Непонятно* — это (предикативное) наречие, выполняющее роль сказуемого в безличном предложении. О правописании "не" с такими наречиями можно посмотреть в части 5 главы 71 ["Справочника по правописанию, произношению и литературному редактированию":](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/20.htm)

*При чём* — это предлог с местоимением. Чтобы отличить сие словосочетание от союза *причём*, имеющего значение *вдобавок*, можно мысленно попробовать заменить его на *к чему* или *для какой цели*.

Comment: *в части 5 главы 71*  - по вашей ссылке нет ни 71-й главы, ни пятой части. Есть - это §56, но там нет примеров на наречия с "не". И есть  §71 части XVII. но там очень много оговорок.

Comment: По моей ссылке есть глава 71, полное название которой — "§71. Правописание не с наречиями". Находится она в разделе "XVII. Правописание частиц". Если у Вас есть ссылка на более удачный источник, то милости прошу.

Comment: Пересвет, ну что за ерунда, ну как может глава назвать "параграф"?! Вам только Сусаниным работать.

Comment: *ПАРАГРАФ <...> 2) глава какого-либо сочинения*. Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка. — Чудинов А.Н.

Comment: Чудинов <...> 1) умер 2) давно умер.  Бегемот.

Comment: *>Проспе́кт (от лат. pro_spectus — вид будущего, вид развития, проектирование будущего, перспектива проекта) — как правило, длинная, прямая и широкая улица в городе[1],* - (Википедия) - если вы пошлете в Москве на Кутузовский, например, проспект вместо Кутузовского проезда (а у меня такой случай был), то вас будут долго и больно бить. Хотя и то и другое - улица.

Comment: "Кутузовский проспект" — это имя собственное, как и "Кутузовский проезд", так что неудачная аналогия. Хотя в любом случае бить не меня будут, а я буду. По крайней мере, так бывает в 85% случаев.

Comment: Название главы - это тоже имя собственное.)))  Короче, в следующий раз прошу не больше не вводить народ в заблуждение, если это было случайно. А если не случайно, то это не делает Вам чести.

Comment: Я в заблуждение никого вводить не собирался. Я считаю, что слово "глава" в данном случае вполне себе синоним слову "параграф".

Comment: Не верю. Ладно, не хотите - как хотите. К сожалению, не могу, да и не считаю нужным объяснять что-то человеку, для которого признание очевидной ошибки - столь сложное занятие. А то, что я перерыл пол-книги прежде чем сообразил, на что вы сослались, это Вам, конечно только в радость.

Comment: Пересвет, ну если написано параграф значком, зачем придумывать синоним?! Только людей путать.

Comment: Я синоним не придумывал, а лишь использовал. Для меня удивительно, что кто-то не понял. Я бы с первого взгляда на оглавление "врубился".